# Создание словаря из файла

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть файл в котором в каждой строчке два числа разделенных запятой: ID студента и ID решенной задачи. 
Пример:

```
1,2
1,4
1,3
2,1
2,2
2,3
2,4
```

Напишите функцию, которая принимает имя файла и возвращает словарь, в котором для каждого студента будет указано количество решенных им задач. Для примера выше результатом будет:

```
{1:3, 2:4}
```

Получившийся код:

```
from collections import Counter
def solved_tasks(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            key,value = line.strip().split(',')
    return {key: Counter(str(value))}
```

Не проходит тесты, как можно исправить ошибку?

Comment: Почему сплит по двоеточию, а не по запятой? И если вы из модуля импортировали функцию, то она вызывается просто `Counter` а не `collections.Counter`

Comment: правили, но все равно выдает ошибку, что не проходит тест

Comment: перенесли return, спасибо, но лучше не стало

Comment: или не в этом проблема?

Comment: А теперь он возвращает такое: {первое число последней строки: 1}. Выводите на печать промежуточные значения и все станет виднее видного. Это же так просто.

Comment: вы имеете ввиду сразу положить их в переменную и потом вернуть?

Comment: Я имею в виду, что с переменными  key и value совершенноничего не делается, кроме того, что их значения переписываются, а предыдущие теряются безвозвратно.